# Transferring 1 .Css File into a .HTML File

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there's a generator to put a .CSS file into a .HTML file so it's only in one file. The CSS would now be in the `<style>` tag instead of a separate file. Is there any generators to do this?

Comment: If you are using webpack to build your project, then you can use [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#styletag) to insert it for you.

Comment: If you're using a build tool, which one? If you're not, what's wrong with copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

you can minify the CSS using a minifier like this one [https://cssminifier.com](https://cssminifier.com/)
and then you can take the output and put it in the `<style>` tag in your HTML